# How can I initialise a variable type array in python with values from an externa config file?

Tags: python, arrays

I got a file with some configuration

```
[ERU]
    refreschtime = 15
    forwardToA = test@gmail.com
    forwardToB = test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com
```

Now I wanted to use forwardToB as an array instead of single string to interact over the array members

```
for recipient in recipients:
     log.info(recipient)
     to_recipients.append(Mailbox(email_address=recipient))
```

The script is working fine for a single recipient. However when try to insert a list of recipients it fail as it take the whole list as single item.

The is how I'm imported the config into the script

```
 try:
        forwardToB = [config.get('ERU', 'forwardToB')]
    except configparser.NoOptionError:
        log.critical('no forwardToB specified in configuration file')
```

Comment: `forwardToB` is still a string. Have you tried splitting the string on `,`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
forwardToB = [elem.strip() for elem in config.get('ERU', 'forwardToB').split(',')]
```

- `split(',')` split a string to an array containing substring separated by a comma in the original string (the comma is not included)
- `strip` is to remove whitespace around your elements